# How do I retrieve data using an AngularJS factory?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server-2008, angularjs

I am having a problem displaying product information from the database using an AngularJS
factory. Basically its a shopping cart application that I modified to display the products from the database instead of a hard coded array.

Heres the main application file source code (app.js) :

```
'use strict';

var shop = angular.module('shop', []);

// create a data service that provides a store and a shopping cart that
// will be shared by all views (instead of creating fresh ones for each view)
shop.factory("DataService",['$http', function($http) {
    // create store
    var myStore = new store($http);

    // return data object with store and cart
    return {
       store: myStore
       //cart: myCart ignore for now
    }
}]);

// adding the config on the module
shop.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider // angular object, injected dynamically
        .when('/', // we show the store on the root
          {
            controller: 'StoreController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/store.htm'
          })
        .when('/cart',
          {
            controller: 'CartController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/cart.htm'
          })
        .when('/checkout',
          {
            controller: 'CheckoutController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/checkout.htm'
          })
       .when('/invoice',
          {
            controller: 'InvoiceController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/invoice.htm'
          })
       .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); // store
    });

var controllers = {};
controllers.StoreController = function($scope, $routeParams, DataService) {
  $scope.store = DataService.store;
  console.log($scope.store);
  //$scope.cart = DataService.cart;
}
```

The store source code (store.js) where I retrieve the data :

```
function store($http) {
  this.products = [];
  this.url = 'php/db.php';
  this.fields = [
    'product_id',
    'product_name', 
    'product_description', 
    'product_price'
  ];
  this.products = this.getProducts($http);
}

store.prototype.getProducts = function($http) {
  $http.post(this.url, { "action" : 'products', "fields" : this.fields })
    .success(function(data, status) {
      //$scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
      //return data;
      this.products = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
      //return data || "Request failed";
      //this.status = status;        
      this.products = [];
  }); 
}

store.prototype.getProduct = function (sku) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    if (this.products[i].sku == sku)
      return this.products[i];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

- Why cant I set my this.product variable to the database result?
- I would also like to extend the products class with more functions to save items
  to the database, how would I go about doing that?

Any advice much appreciated.

Regards

**UPDATE**

I have added the app.js code below, I am having an issue with the controller (StoreController) when accessing the data from the store class (store.js).
It still shows an empty array. I have changed my code as suggested by m.e.conroy.

app.js

```
'use strict';

var shop = angular.module('shop', []);


shop.factory("DataService",['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    // create store
    var myStore = new store($http, $q);
    return {
       store: myStore      
    }
}]);


// adding the config on the module
shop.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider // angular object, injected dynamically
        .when('/', // we show the store on the root
          {
            controller: 'StoreController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/store.htm'
          })
        .when('/cart',
          {
            controller: 'CartController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/cart.htm'
          })
        .when('/checkout',
          {
            controller: 'CheckoutController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/checkout.htm'
          })
       .when('/invoice',
          {
            controller: 'InvoiceController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/invoice.htm'
          })
       .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); // store
    });

var controllers = {};
controllers.StoreController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, DataService) {
  $scope.store = DataService.store;              
}

shop.controller(controllers);
```

Comment: DataService.store return a promise, so you need to resolve to catch the value. And it seems that you store function doesn't return the result object... you need to return this object. Can you create a plunker example with this full store factory implementation?

Comment: Look this nice example of angularjs app https://github.com/andreev-artem/angular_experiments/tree/master/examples/architecture and here http://jsfiddle.net/u5gV2/ for simple memory cache.

Comment: the data which is returned is undefined. in the code I set the this.products variable to that which is returned in the success handler.

Comment: You don't need to set `this.products = this.getProducts($http)` if you're going to set `this.products` in the success or error functions of the `$http.post`  You're not even returning anything from `getProducts` so `this.products` is being set to the definition of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function store($http) {
    this.products = [];
    this.url = 'php/db.php';
    this.fields = ['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_price'];
    this.products = this.getProducts($http);
}

store.prototype.getProducts = function ($http) {
    return $http.post(this.url, {
        "action": 'products',
        "fields": this.fields
    })
    .success(function (data, status) {
        return data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status) { 
        return [];
    });
}
```

When you return `$http.post` you're returning the `promise` it creates, so `this.products` would contain the `$http` promise.  When the call returns from the server the promise is resolved by the `success` or `error` functions returning data in those functions sets the variable `this.products` to what is returned.

In this case `this.products = []` is getting replaced right away by the promise from `$http.` If you try to access that data in your application before the resolve happens you'll get back the promise it contains which could cause problems if you try and use it in other functions as if it contained the array you need.  You can use `$q.when` to "wait" on the promise to resolve and then assign the returned data, so if you try to use `this.products` elsewhere before then it will still contain an empty array and thus code like `this.products.length` will still work instead of throwing an error. So you could do the following:

```
function store($http,$q) {
    this.products = [];
    this.url = 'php/db.php';
    this.fields = ['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_price'];
    $q.when(this.getProducts($http)).then(function(data){ this.products = data; });
}
```

If you do decide to go this route, just take note that you'll need to inject `$q` into your service and then pass it on through your `new` operator during class creation.  This would resolve any race situation you may have in your controller.

Of course you could also use the `resolve` provided for the `.when` method of the `$routeProvider` to resolve and controller dependencies prior to the controller taking "control"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed my code and updated the question with my controllers. Just need a little more direction. Thanks!

Comment: Did you change your `store.js` as well to add in `$q`?

Comment: I did some testing and while in my example the `this.getProducts` for the store gets called and returns the proper value in the `$q` statement the value in `$scope.store` in the controller never gets set.  I have a feeling that doing it this way won't work during object creation.  I suggest going the pure Angular route and using a factory service as your object store (service).

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and advice, marking the question as answered.

Comment: @Chesney, glad I could help some, it may not be the way you wanted to code but I'm glad I could at least give you some insight.  Hope your project goes well and hope you stick with Angular, once you get used to it, it really is a time saver.

Comment: Thanks @m.e.conroy I really appreciate your help. I made a few modifications and now everything is working the Angular way ;) I will post the project on github when I am finished.

Comment: Hi @m-e-conroy can you assist on another AngularJS matter? I have an issue with filters. I posted the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948280/angularjs-not-filtering-products-list/19948349?noredirect=1#19948349