# AngularJS not filtering products list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, filtering

I am having an issue with AngularJS filtering my products list. I have done a few console.log queries on my variables and all seem fine. The problem is that the view does not update to show the filtered products.

Filtering works perfectly fine when you enter the search text in the input box **but it does not work when clicking on the Category menu items.**

I would like to filter the product list by category when the user clicks on the menu item.

Please see my code below and any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

**My app.js**

```
myApp.controller('StoreController', function($scope, $filter, storeFactory, cartFactory) {
  $scope.cartTotal = 0;
  $scope.cartItems = [];
  $scope.categories = [];
  $scope.counted = 0;
  $scope.filteredProducts = {};

  //get the products
  storeFactory.getProducts(function(results) {
    $scope.products = results.products;
    $scope.counted = $scope.products.length;
    $scope.filteredProducts = results.products; 
  });

  $scope.$watch("search", function(query){
    if($scope.filteredProducts.length) { 
      $scope.filteredProducts = $filter("filter")($scope.products, query);
      $scope.counted = $scope.filteredProducts.length; 
    }
  });

  $scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(categoryName){
    console.log('category filter');
    /*$scope.products.forEach(function(o,i){
      console.log('filter');
      if( o.category_id !== categoryId ){
       $scope.filteredProducts.splice(i,1);
       console.log('removing');
       console.log(o);
      }
    });*/
    $scope.filteredProducts = $filter("filter")($scope.filteredProducts, categoryName);
    console.info('the filtered items');
    console.log($scope.filteredProducts);
    $scope.counted = $scope.filteredProducts.length;
  } 

  $scope.getCategories = function(){
    storeFactory.getCategories(function(results){
      $scope.categories = results.rows; 
    });
  }

      $scope.getCategories();
});
```

**My store.htm**

UPDATE :
I removed the extra controller reference and wrapped everything in one div.

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController">

      <!-- the sidebar product menu -->
       <div class="block-content collapse in">
        <div class="daily" ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy:'name'">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div ng-click="filterProductsByCategory(category.category_name)" class="accordion-toggle collapsed">{{category.category_name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
      </div>

      <!-- Load store items start -->
        <div class="label">Showing {{counted}} Product(s)</div> 
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts | orderBy:'product_name'" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 550px;">
          <hr></hr>
          <div class="span1" style="width: 120px;">

            <!--         <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#carouselLightBox"> -->
            <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#carouselLightBox{{product.product_id}}">
            <!--img alt={{ product.product_name }} ng-src="{{product.image}}" src="{{product.image}}" /-->
                <img id="tmp" class="" src="images/products/{{product.product_image_filename}}" alt=""></img>
            </a>
            <div class="lightbox hide fade" id="carouselLightBox{{product.product_id}}" style="display: none;">
              <div class='lightbox-content'>
                <img src="images/products/{{product.product_image_filename}}" alt="" />
                  <!--img alt={{ product.product_name }} ng-src="{{product.image}}" src="{{product.image}}" /-->
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="close_lightbox"  ng-click="closeBox(product.product_id, $event)">Close</button>
              </div>
                <style>
                  #close_lightbox
                  {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 5px;
                    right: 5px;
                  }
                </style>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="span6" style="width: 330px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <h5 style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">{{product.product_name}}</h5>
            <p>{{product.product_description }}</p>
            <p>Category : {{product.category_name}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
            <p class="price">Price : <strong>R{{ product.product_price }}</strong></p>
              </div>
        </div>

    <!-- end of controller -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Is your `$scope.$watch('search'...` working?  I don't see `$scope.search` for which the `$watch` statement would be keeping tabs on.

Comment: The reason I ask the above, is that you could just use your `$watch` statement via your `filterProductsByCategory` function by setting the `$scope.search` term to the category name.

Comment: Hi @m.e.conroy thanks for the quick reply. Yes, an input box is set with with a ng-model = "search". How do I go about doing what you suggested - "you could just use your $watch statement via your filterProductsByCategory function by setting the $scope.search term to the category name."

Comment: See the answer I posted below, I attached a fiddle as well to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.filteredProducts = {};

//get the products
storeFactory.getProducts(function (results) {
    $scope.products = results.products;
    $scope.counted = $scope.products.length;
    $scope.filteredProducts = results.products;
});
```

Is `results.products` an array of objects or an object of objects?  Because `$filter('filter')($scope.products,query);` expects `$scope.products` to be an array.

```
$scope.$watch("search", function (query) {
    if($scope.filteredProducts.length) {
        $scope.filteredProducts = $filter("filter")($scope.products, query);
        $scope.counted = $scope.filteredProducts.length;
    }
});
```

Here's what I'm thinking this should look like and you won't need the `$watch` statement or the `filteredProducts` array/object, In controller:

```
$scope.search = '';
$scope.products = [];
$scope.categories = ['category1','category2','category3'];

// assuming that your store function getProducts returns a promise here
storeFactory.getProducts().then(function(results){
    $scope.products = results.products; // needs to be an array of product objects
});

$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
    $scope.search = category;
};
```

Then in your HTML Partial, this is not exactly how your's is, I'm just showing you here in shorter form what is possible:

```
<button ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-click="filterProductsByCategory(cat)">{{cat}}</button>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy:'product_name'">
    <!-- Product Information Here -->
</div>
```

I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/QL28C/1/
You can free form search with any term or click a button for a category.

Comment: Thanks! @m.e.conroy I will have a look and do the changes just now and will provide feedback in a moment. Thanks again

Comment: Sure no problem, again - just here to help.  Hope it was what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

The side bar is using one instance of StoreController, and the main div is using another instance of StoreController. Each instance having its own scope. The should both use the same controller instance: wrap everything inside a div, and use a unique StoreController for this wrapping div.

Comment: Thanks! the reason I did it like this was intended for styling purposes. I will do the modifications and will reply asap if its working

Comment: Hi @jb-nizet I removed the extra controller statement and wrapped everything in one div with ng-controller="StoreController" but its still not updating the view (filtering the products).